# Does it possible use read only committed in Teradata?

Tags: database, teradata, isolation-level, read-committed

I have found that Teradata uses:

```
READ_ISOLATION_LEVEL= ACCESS|READ|WRITE
```

How it correspond to usual read commited/dirty in usual databases?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this addresses your question entirely:

`ACCESS` locking would allow dirty reads allows `WRITE` lock to be in place. `READ` locking allows only committed reads and can block `WRITE/EXCLUSIVE` locks while reading data. `WRITE` lock prevents `READ` locks from access data but allows `ACCESS` (dirty read) lock to access data.